# Image not Showing with Meteor Template

Tags: templates, meteor

I am pretty new to coding and even newer to meteor.

I have the following code in my html file in a client folder in a Metoer app and the image image1.jpg in a public folder which is in the client folder.

The image shows as broken in the browser.

```
<head>
  <title>image_share</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Coursera!</h1>

  {{> images}}
</body>

<template name="images">
  <img src="image1.jpg" alt="Popey Village" />
</template>
```

Comment: After moving the public folder outside of the client folder the image appears on the browser.

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you have solved your issue, you can post it as an _answer_ below and accept it.